# Drawing a coloured border around an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Hey I'm trying to put a coloured border around an image in MATLAB and I can't for the life of me see why this isn't working:

```
clear, close all, clc

A = imread('syd.jpg')

[m n o] = size(A)
border_width = 25;

border = zeros(m+(border_width*2),n+(border_width*2),3);

c = [randi(255) randi(255) randi(255)];

border(:,:,1) = c(1);
border(:,:,2) = c(2);
border(:,:,3) = c(3);

for i = 1 : m
    for j = 1 : n
        border(m+border_width,n+border_width,:) = A(m,n,:);
    end
end

imshow(uint8(border));
```

All I get is a block coloured image, maybe I'm just missing something small, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for`-loop, you are indexing with `m` and `n`, instead of `i` and  `j`. Variables  `m` and `n` are constants, meaning you are just setting the value of one pixel in your code.

Try with this:

```
for i = 1 : m
    for j = 1 : n
        border(i+border_width,j+border_width,:) = (A(i,j,:));
    end
end
```

Comment: Oh dear, I knew it must be something simple, silly me! Thank you very much. :)